# Parse MediaWiki Template-Block

Tags: php, regex, mediawiki-templates

I have a little problem with parsing a MediaWiki Template-Block: http://regex101.com/r/dD1hC9/1

- The RegEx I use to get the template from the text is: `\{\{Template1 (.+?)\}\}`.
- The template: `{{Template1 |Parameter1=Text |Parameter2=Text |Parameter3={{Template2|hier|steht|text}} |Parameter4=Text }}`

Is there any possibility, to parse the complete block in an associative array (`parametername => value`), without loosing the template in Parameter3 respectively in all parameters?

Comment: You should add the regex to the question.

Comment: You can see the regex in the link.

Comment: I've included the regex and the template to parse.

Comment: `<offtopic>` You don't have to escape the `{` and `}`s. They stand as literals when used alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$subject = "{{Template1 |Parameter1=Text |Parameter2=Text |Parameter3={{Template2|hier|steht|text}} |Parameter4=Text }}";
preg_match('/{{Template1(.*)}}/', $subject, $matches);
preg_match_all('/ \|(\w+)=({{.*?}}|\w*)/', $matches[1], $matches);
$a = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($a);
?>
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [Parameter1] => Text
    [Parameter2] => Text
    [Parameter3] => {{Template2|hier|steht|text}}
    [Parameter4] => Text
)
```

Comment: This works well if you have only one template in the string, but not if you have multiple templates, alas.